# How to compare if any value is similar to any other using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have many pairs of coordinate arrays like so

```
a=[(1.001,3),(1.334, 4.2),...,(17.83, 3.4)]
b=[(1.002,3.0001),(1.67, 5.4),...,(17.8299, 3.4)]
c=[(1.00101,3.002),(1.3345, 4.202),...,(18.6, 12.511)]
```

Any coordinate in any of the pairs can be a duplicate of another coordinate in another array of pairs. The arrays are also not the same size.

The duplicates will vary slightly in their value and for an example, I would consider the first value in a, b and c to be duplicates.

I could iterate through each array and compare the values one by one using numpy.isclose, however that will be slow.

Is there an efficient way to tackle this problem, hopefully using numpy to keep computing times low?

Comment: What is the output you want? A new list with the duplicated coordinates? Or you wanna filter them out of the originals?..

Comment: A new array with the duplicates either grouped together, averaged, or an index array that links the duplicates to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna try the round() function which will round off the numbers in your lists to the nearest integers.
the next thing that I'd suggest might be too extreme:

concat the arrays and put them into a pandas dataframe and drop_duplicates()

this might not be the solution you want

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at numpy.testing if you allow for AsertionError handling.

```
from numpy import testing as ts

a = np.array((1.001,3))
b = np.array((1.000101, 3.002))

ts.assert_array_almost_equal(a, b, decimal=1)  # output None
```

but

```
ts.assert_array_almost_equal(a, b, decimal=3)
```

results in

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 3 decimals
Mismatch: 50%
Max absolute difference: 0.002
Max relative difference: 0.00089891
 x: array([1.001, 3.   ])
 y: array([1.   , 3.002])
```

There are some more interesting functions from numpy.testing. Make sure to take a look at [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.testing.html).

Comment: Not sure that answers the question. How'd you do that for 3 arrays of many coordinates?

Comment: Well if you don't want to compare the entire array at once, you will have to iterate over the coordinates inside the array and test it separately, tbh.

Comment: Not true, there are some way using vectorized operations that avoid the explicit pythonic for loop !

Comment: Yeah, I am talking specifically about the way as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `pandas` to give you an intuitive result, rather than just numbers. Of course you can expand the solution to your need

Say you create a `pd.DataFrame` from each array, and tag them from which array each belongs to. I am rounding the results to 2 decimal places, you may use whatever tolerance you want

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a).round(2)
dfa['arr'] = 'a'
```

Then, by concatenating, using `duplicated` and sorting, you may find an intuitive Dataframe that might fulfill your needs

```
df = pd.concat([dfa, dfb, dfc])

df[df.duplicated(subset=[0,1], keep=False)].sort_values(by=[0,1])
```

yields

```
    x       y   arr
0   1.00    3.0 a
0   1.00    3.0 b
0   1.00    3.0 c
1   1.33    4.2 a
1   1.33    4.2 c
2   17.83   3.4 a
2   17.83   3.4 b
```

The indexes are duplicated, so you can simply use `reset_index()` at the end and use the newly-generated column as a parameter that indicates the corresponding index on each array. I.e.:

```
    index   x       y   arr
0   0       1.00    3.0 a
1   0       1.00    3.0 b
2   0       1.00    3.0 c
3   1       1.33    4.2 a
4   1       1.33    4.2 c
5   2       17.83   3.4 a
6   2       17.83   3.4 b
```

So, for example, line 0 indicates a duplicate coordinate, and is found on `index` 0 of `arr` `a`. Line 1 also indicates a dupe coordinate, found or `index` 0 of `arr` `b`, etc.

---

Now, if you just want to delete the duplicates and get *one final array* with only non-duplicate values, you may use`drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0,1])[[0,1]].to_numpy()
```

which yields

```
array([[ 1.  ,  3.  ],
       [ 1.33,  4.2 ],
       [17.83,  3.4 ],
       [ 1.67,  5.4 ],
       [18.6 , 12.51]])
```